# Storing arrays of different length in one matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a number of arrays of different sizes, e.g.
`A=1:10; B=1:9` etc.

Now I want to save these arrays into one big matrix. In this example I would want it to be 2x10, with NaN for the remaining spot not filled by array B. I know how to preallocate this matrix with NaN(size), but my question here is how to get these arrays in with their different lengths. It must be a super simple command, but I just can't seem to think of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the column indices:

```
 >> BigMat = NaN(2,10);
 >> BigMat(1, 1:numel(A) ) = A;
 >> BigMat(2, 2:numel(B) ) = B;
```

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at [`cell`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) structures. They can contain a variety of different data types. For example

```
BigMat{1}=A;
BigMat{2}=B;
BigMat{3}='Some text string'
```